# How to not dismiss the alert box when clicking outside of it on Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am building a ionic 2 app and I am using the following component

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert

```
  import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyPage {
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that when I click outside the box the alert is not dismissed?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Ionic 2/3:

As you can see in [the AlertController docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#advanced), you can use the `enableBackdropDismiss` (boolean) option when creating the alert:

> **enableBackdropDismiss**: Whether the alert should be dismissed by tapping the backdrop. Default
> true

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...
export class MyPage {

  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}

  showAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      subTitle: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just accepted your friend request!',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      enableBackdropDismiss: false // <- Here! :)
    });

    alert.present();
  }
}
```

### Ionic 4/5:

In Ionic 4/5 [this property](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#properties) has been renamed to `backdropDismiss`:

> **backdropDismiss**: If true, the alert will be dismissed when the backdrop is clicked.

```
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

//...
export class MyPage {

  constructor(public alertController: AlertController) {}

  async showAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      backdropDismiss: false // <- Here! :)
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: in ionic 4, ' backdropDismiss: false '

Comment: Thanks @PradipVadher, I've updated the answer to include the information related to Ionic 4 :)

Answer (score 14):

In ionic 4 the option has been renamed to

```
backdropDismiss: false
```

Comment: add some more detail

Comment: Not sure what extra detail you are looking for, the accepted answer is valid for previous versions of Ionic on the latest Ionic 4 the parameter has been renamed from enableBackdropDismiss to backdropDismiss

Comment: @Pete is correct, for those using IONIC 4, you will have to use this option instead.

Comment: You rock dude! Saved me a couple of minutes there :)

Answer (score 2):

Set enableBackdropDismiss: false in the alertCtrl.create options